# Какой нужен VNC сервер, чтобы не подключаться к X-сессии, а именно имитировать физический ввод и вывод?

Tags: linux, vnc

Какой установить и как настроить VNC сервер, чтобы изображение на клиенте было то-же самое, что и на физическом экране сервера, а ввод на клавиатуре на клиенте был равносилен вводу на физической клавиатуре? Причем это должно работать как в менеджере окон, так и вне его - например когда без оболочки включен терминал или графическая программа.

Comment: насколько мне известно, никакой и никак.

Comment: *нужно, чтобы был ввод-вывод и вне менеджера окон - то есть терминальная сессия то-же должна передаваться по VNC. Мне нужен самый нормальный захват экрана и имитация физического ввода, а не подключение к X-серверу* — а это вообще о чём? связи с остальным вопросом не просматривается.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я обновил вопрос. Уверен, вы его не поняли.

Comment: Как я помню наши любимые vnc соеденяются к x серверу и им управляют, без x сервера не думаю что это будет вообще возможно. Также во время перехода в консоль все процессы пользователя не смогут лезть в консоль (хотя мы можем например слышать музыку, если конечноже pulse не включено прерывание его) А так ответ нет.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров Жаль, мне нужно протестировать PCSX удаленно, но не хочется устанавливать оболочку.

Comment: Так может вам нужен не vnc а удаленный ssh сервер?

Comment: Вы сможете через туже reminna на убанте (домашн компе) подключится к ssh который находится у вас в облаке и писать и получать вывод из консоли.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров PSCX - это графическая программа, эмулятор PS1. Как я на неё через ssh буду смотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, вам нужна программа `vino`. Для ubuntu нужно поставить пакет **vino**. GUI-конфигуратор запускается под xorg как vino-preferences. В командной строке пароль для vnc можно поменять через vino-passwd.
Сам сервер не находится в PATH, и запускается vino-preferences, запустить вручную его можно в xorg так:

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server &
```

Comment: а если у меня нет менеджера окон (если вы знаете что это)?

Comment: мне надо, чтоб vnc сервер захватывал изображение с физического экрана и имитировал ввод с физической клавиатуры, а не подключался к сессии менеджера окон

Comment: Менеджер окон не нужен, нужна только X-Window

Answer (score 0):

Для текстовой консоли есть `linuxvnc`. Запускается от рута с указанием номера виртуальной консоли. Есть ошибки отображения и не все кнопки работают.